# How to fix a broken pip in anaconda without removing dependent packages?

Tags: pip, conda, miniconda

When I try to install something with `pip` I get the message

```
You are using pip version 18.0, however version 18.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Though, when I follow the advise here, I get:

> Collecting pip   Using cached
>   https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c2/d7/90f34cb0d83a6c5631cf71dfe64cc1054598c843a92b400e55675cc2ac37/pip-18.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
>   Exception: Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/.../miniconda3/envs/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/**init**.py",
>   line 2862, in _dep_map
>       return self.**dep_map   File "/home/.../miniconda3/envs/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init**.py",
>   line 2669, in **getattr**
>       raise AttributeError(attr) AttributeError: _DistInfoDistribution__dep_map
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/.../miniconda3/envs/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/packaging/requirements.py",
>   line 93, in **init**
>       req = REQUIREMENT.parseString(requirement_string)   File "/home/.../miniconda3/envs/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyparsing.py",
>   line 1632, in parseString
>       raise exc   File "/home/.../miniconda3/envs/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyparsing.py",
>   line 1622, in parseString
>       loc, tokens = self._parse( instring, 0 )   File "/home/.../miniconda3/envs/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyparsing.py",
>   line 1379, in _parseNoCache
>       loc,tokens = self.parseImpl( instring, preloc, doActions )   File "/home/.../miniconda3/envs/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyparsing.py",
>   line 3395, in parseImpl
>       loc, exprtokens = e._parse( instring, loc, doActions )   File "/home/.../miniconda3/envs/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyparsing.py",
>   line 1383, in _parseNoCache
>       loc,tokens = self.parseImpl( instring, preloc, doActions )   File "/home/.../miniconda3/envs/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyparsing.py",
>   line 3183, in parseImpl
>       raise ParseException(instring, loc, self.errmsg, self) pip._vendor.pyparsing.ParseException: Expected stringEnd (at char 33),
>   (line:1, col:34)
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/.../miniconda3/envs/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/**init**.py",
>   line 2942, in **init**
>       super(Requirement, self).**init**(requirement_string)   File "/home/.../miniconda3/envs/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/packaging/requirements.py",
>   line 97, in **init**
>       requirement_string[e.loc:e.loc + 8])) pip._vendor.packaging.requirements.InvalidRequirement: Invalid
>   requirement, parse error at "'; extra '"
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/.../miniconda3/envs/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/basecommand.py",
>   line 228, in main
>       status = self.run(options, args)   File "/home/.../miniconda3/envs/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py",
>   line 318, in run
>       self._warn_about_conflicts(to_install)   File "/home/.../miniconda3/envs/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py",
>   line 442, in _warn_about_conflicts
>       package_set, _dep_info = check_install_conflicts(to_install)   File
>   "/home/.../miniconda3/envs/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/check.py",
>   line 89, in check_install_conflicts
>       state = create_package_set_from_installed()   File "/home/.../miniconda3/envs/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/check.py",
>   line 39, in create_package_set_from_installed
>       retval[name] = PackageDetails(dist.version, dist.requires())   File
>   "/home/.../miniconda3/envs/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/**init**.py",
>   line 2613, in requires
>       dm = self._dep_map   File "/home/.../miniconda3/envs/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/**init**.py",
>   line 2864, in _dep_map
>       self.**dep_map = self._compute_dependencies()   File "/home/.../miniconda3/envs/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init**.py",
>   line 2874, in _compute_dependencies
>       reqs.extend(parse_requirements(req))   File "/home/.../miniconda3/envs/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/**init**.py",
>   line 2935, in parse_requirements
>       yield Requirement(line)   File "/home/.../miniconda3/envs/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/**init**.py",
>   line 2944, in **init**
>       raise RequirementParseError(str(e)) pip._vendor.pkg_resources.RequirementParseError: Invalid requirement,
>   parse error at "'; extra '" You are using pip version 18.0, however
>   version 18.1 is available. You should consider upgrading via the 'pip
>   install --upgrade pip' command.

I tried `conda install pip` that did not help. when I try `conda remove pip` it wants to remove all the dependent packages, which is not what I really want to do. Any idea how to fix it without screwing up my environment?

Comment: `conda remove --force` removes just that package without touching the dependencies, as explained in `conda remove --help`

Answer (score 0):

This particular problem was caused by `testpath`. I removed that package with `pip remove testpath` and then I could update pip without errors. Unfortunately, the error message did not point me there. I found this solution at a GitHub issue page.

https://github.com/conda-forge/testpath-feedstock/issues/7